# Is it possible to use map on methods like List.append

Tags: python

I am wondering if you can use mapping like this:

```
x = ["a"]
y = ["b","c","d"]
map(x.append,y)
```

I would like x = ["a","b","c","d"], However this does not happen

Comment: Why not do x.extend(y) easily? This returns what you want. Also, extend function takes a list as input as I know. With map() it would try to take an element, since map gives elements of an iterable to a function one by one and returns the result as a list again.

Comment: The reason you aren't getting results is because you aren't consuming the map object. Anyway, you should use `append` instead of `extend`, but this is not the best way of doing it.

Comment: Well though I am sure extend is not good for this case, it was more of a general question as to how map works I suppose

Comment: I will edit the question

Answer (score 3):

`map` returns an iterator, so nothing happens as long as you don't iterate on it. You could make that happen by calling `list` on it:

```
x = ["a"]
y = ["b","c","dx"]
list(map(x.extend,y))
# [None, None, None]
print(x)
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'x']
```

Note that, as `extend` expects an iterable (which str objects are), it will iterate on each string in `y` and append the characters, so you'll get `'d'` and `'x'` in the example above.

You probably meant to use `append`:

```
x = ["a"]
y = ["b","c","dx"]
list(map(x.append,y))
# [None, None, None]
print(x)
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'dx']
```

But anyway, `map` is meant to yield the results of applying the function to the items of the iterable (here, the `None` returned by `x.append()`), and using it for the side effect of the function makes things rather unclear.

Comment: Is there any other way that I could similarly do this? Like are there any inbuilt functions or should I just create my own to get the "side effect " of a function?

Comment: Mostly because I have something I want to execute and that, when executed, applies a function to one whole list

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ["a"]
y = ["b","c","d"]
x.extend(y)
print (x)
```

output:

```
 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

The extend() extends the list by adding all items of a list (passed as an argument) to the end.

The syntax of extend() method is:

> list1.extend(list2)

Here, the elements of list2 are added to the end of list1.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason for doing this?

`map` is a worst choice in case of readability and execution speed.

```
x = ["a"]
y = ["b","c","d"]
x.extend(y)
```

Comment: `extend` works in-place, so assigning the return value results in `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Extend function takes a list as input as I know. With map() it would try to take an element, since map gives elements of an iterable to a function one by one and returns the result as a list again.

This should do

```py
x.extend(y)
```